# implementing abstract methods in matlab

Tags: matlab, oop, methods, subclass, abstract

I'm new to MATLAB OOP. I have an abstract class defining an abstract method in my matlab path. I have a subclass named SubAbsClass in a subfolder named @SubAbsClass. I cannot create an object of the subclass after implementing the abstract method in the subclass. Here's my SubAbsClass implementation:

```
classdef SubAbsClass < AbsClass

    properties
        O1
    end

methods
        function obj=SubAbsClass(a,b)
            obj.O1=absMethod(a,b);
        end
    end
    methods (Static)

        function out = absMethod(a,b)
            out = a + b;
        end
    end
end
```

and my abstract class implementation is:

```
classdef AbsClass
    methods(Abstract, Static)
        result = absMethod
    end
end
```

when I try to create an object in the MATLAB path (the abstract class is in the MATLAB path), I get an error. I have tried many configurations and searched the matlab oop document, and also the web including stackoverflow but unfortunately couldn't find an example to implement. I appreciate your help

```
>> clear all; clear classes;
>> obj=SubAbsClass(5,2)
Undefined function 'absMethod' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in SubAbsClass (line 11)
            obj.O1=absMethod(a,b);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a method, Matlab considers non-dot references to be calls to local functions (defined outside the `classdef` block within the class file) or to a function somewhere on the Matlab path following the usual look-up rules.

So you need to call the `Static` method via the instance `obj` in the constructor:

```
methods
    function obj = SubAbsClass(a,b)
        obj.O1 = obj.absMethod(a,b);
    end
end
```

One little caveat to the above is that non-`Static` methods also have a functional form.
So *if the method was not `Static`*, this notation would also work

```
methods
    function obj = SubAbsClass(a,b)
        obj.O1 = absMethod(obj,a,b);
    end
end
```

Which, I think, is almost equivalent to the dot notation, although it has been said to be ["generally" faster](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2012/03/26/considering-performance-in-object-oriented-matlab-code/#11) (albeit, that was four years ago).

Here are the details for [ordinary method](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/method-invocation.html) invocation and [`Static` method](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/static-methods.html) invocation.